# SQL Server update multiple columns and add missing rows based on a key from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert, sql-update

I would like in SQL Server to update multiple columns [C1], [C2], in a destination table A from a source table B based on a common non numerical column key [Key] and add missing rows (including the key) in the destination table A. Both tables A and B have exactly the same Columns including the key. The constraint is to not delete from A any record ever. I don't mind if data are not actual but I do mind if data are missing. So no DROP no Truncate I believe. What is the most efficient way to do it?

Example tables

```
    Destination Table A with columns:
[Key][C1][C2]
    A, 1, 2
    B, 3, 4
    C, 5, 6

    SourceTable B with columns:
[Key][C1][C2]
    A, 2, 1
    B, 3, 4
    C, 7, 6
    D, 0, 0
```

Expected outcome A to be exactly like B

```
    Destination Table A:
[Key][C1][C2]
    A, 2, 1
    B, 3, 4
    C, 7, 6
    D, 0, 0
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if something is deleted from Table B at a later point e.g., the row with the key A, when updated it should also be deleted from table A.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this keyword :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx

And this is the solution:

```
   ;MERGE INTO [Table_A] AS Target  
    USING (SELECT [B1],[B2],[B3] FROM [Table_B])
           AS Source ([B1],[B2],[B3])  
    ON Target.[A1] = Source.[B1]  
    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE 
    SET [A2] = Source.[B2],
        [A3] = Source.[B3]  
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN  
    INSERT ([A1],[A2],[A3]) VALUES ([B1],[B2],[B3]);
```

And the code to remove the extra keys in table A :

```
;WITH IdsToDelete ([A1]) AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT [A1]
    FROM [Table_A]
    WHERE [A1] NOT IN (SELECT [B1] FROM [Table_B])

)
DELETE t1 
FROM [Table_A] t1 
    JOIN IdsToDelete itd ON t1.[A1] = itd.[A1]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it going to work when something is deleted though? E.g., when something gets deleted from Table B it should also get deleted from Table A.

Comment: No, I think you have to make another treatment.

Comment: I though so. Also this query updates all rows for me not only the changing ones

Comment: Just for the record what I have done eventually instead of update records was in a transaction to truncate the table and insert all values again. That was not what I wanted but it seemed to be the easier way to do it.